# Using the Coldbox framework, is there a way to intercept a renderView call and execute a different template?

Tags: coldfusion, coldbox

I am trying to learn Coldbox to perhaps replace the current framework I am using.  One of the features that I currently use is the ability to override any of the template inclusions by convention.

Essentially, lets say I have a view, "views/home.cfm"

```
<h1>I am the default theme</h1>
```

and that is all well and good.  But lets say that I have a different view, "themes/[theme-name]/views/home.cfm"

```
<h1>I am the user chosen theme</h1>
```

that I want to include conditionally (say there is a cookie to determine what theme is in use).  Also, if the file does not exist, the default/fallback view should be rendered.

Is there any way of doing this overriding the system functions?

I looked at interceptors, and the preViewRender and postViewRender interceptors seem like the place to do something like this, but there doesn't seem to be any way of manipulating the actual workflow.  If seems to be mainly pre/post processing of the content.  For instance, there doesn't seem to be a way to "return false" to tell the renderView method to not actually render the view.  Or any way to affect the location in which the view is to be found.

Any ideas?

Comment: might wanna ask here instead: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/coldbox

Comment: That is definitely my fallback, though I'd much rather use stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tyler,

The ColdBox Framework is quite flexible. It is possible to do what you desire but I don't think modifying renderView() is the best way to resolve this--although, you most definitely can.

I would encourage you to create a User Defined Function in the /includes/helpers/ApplicationHelper.cfm file that contains the logic you require. The functions that are added to this helper file are accessible from anywhere in the framework. This would allow you to create a function called "renderSkin()" that contains the logic you need. RenderSkin() would ultimitly call "renderView()" when you finally figured out which template you wanted to render for that user.

Respectfully,

Aaron Greenlee

Comment: This is probably the best/only answer, but I'm going to give it a few more days to see if I get any other responses before accepting.  Perhaps I should submit a feature request to expand on the events for ViewRender.  The thing is I want to keep to the framework as much as possible, so using my own method would seem to me to be a large departure.

Comment: The RenderView() method is designed to do just that. It's only a framework--you still need to solve problems that are unique to you. You may also want to post on the ColdBox Google Group. Perhaps one of the other ColdBox team members will have different advice.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you go with the interceptor route, but change the layout instead of the view.

From the `postEvent` interceptor you can get the `processedEvent` key from the `interceptData` to change the layout.

Otherwise you could just make the check part of the layout page. The layout can the be a switch statement (or a more OO approach) $including the themed layout files as needed. This has the advantage of giving you a chance to emit custom interception points and having common functionality (css, js)

Comment: This isn't just about the layout of the site, but given a theme being able to change the views as well.  For instance being able to use a unordered list instead of a table.  Giving theme developers the ability to change everything.

Comment: Then use the postEvent interceptor and update the view to match your them. Something like `event.setView( theme + event.getCurrentView );`

Comment: Is there any way to set the view to be rendered in the preViewRender event?

Comment: Looking over the Render.cfc plugin, the `preViewRender` event is actually called in the render view function. Its too late to change the view at this point. (its really not that well named).